# Coherence with JBosss 6.1.EAP /Jboss as 7

Tags: java, caching, jboss

I am trying to find some document/references related to Jboss and coherence set up for Jboss 6.1 Eap. Some reference I found is old and seeing most of the integration with websphere and weblogic server but not with current Jboss versions. Just want to check if some one did the integration recently or any reference will be helpful.

Thanks,
Pinaki

Comment: which version of Coherence?

Comment: Oracle coherence 12c with Jboss 6.1 EAP.